# Can't make "user switch notifications work" via notificationCenter

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsnotification

I am trying to use NSWorkspaceSessionDidBecomeActiveNotification to detect fast user switching but it doesn't seems to fire my handler.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification { 
     [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(switchHandler:)
     name:NSWorkspaceSessionDidBecomeActiveNotification
     object:nil]; 
 }

- (void) switchHandler:(NSNotification*) notification { 
     NSLog(@"User switch detected");
}
```

I use Apple's example [Apple Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPMultipleUsers/Concepts/UserSwitchNotifications.html).
Am I missing something?

Cheers

Comment: I put it under awakeFromNib instead of applicationDidFinishLaunching and it worked! But I don't know why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I should have connected my app delegate object to File's Owner/Application's delegate outlet.

awakeFromNib doesn't need that, that's why it worked.